# Where exactly on android emulator app goes? Is it case at max 2 app at a time, if that's the case how to remove?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I have recently started with Android dev using Eclipse/ADT. I made couple of apps (Hello, android, Test) and could see them on android (not sure but they both seem to have got install on simulator) [image]

[image]

What is happening now whatever app i make it runs fine but i do not see it on emulator. I downloaded a 2 activity example from http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/ I could open project in eclipse and run it but just could not see it on simulator. This is my first time with mobile development so i might be missing something obvious.

I noticed i am having following 2 warning while running app.

WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!

Could this be reason how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've never encountered a limit to how many different apps I can load to the emulator, so I can't really speak to that issue.

Removing an app is easy (pretty much just like your phone would work).

1) Bring up your app list
2) Hit the menu button
3) Select "Manage Apps"
4) Click on the app
5) Click on "Uninstall"

Comment: Why i would not be able to see my app on andriod??